# Converting a recursive function to a tail recursive function in Scheme

Tags: binary, integer, scheme, bit

I have a function:

```
;; Converting list of integers to a bit string
(define (convert-integers-to-bits integer-representation-of-bits)
  (if (null? integer-representation-of-bits)
    '#*
    (bit-string-append 
      (convert-integers-to-bits (cdr integer-representation-of-bits))
      (unsigned-integer->bit-string 1 (car integer-representation-of-bits)))))
```

When I run it on small lists, it works, but on real files, it gives me the warning:

```
;Aborting!: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Sample usage:

```
]=> (convert-integers-to-bits '(1 1 0 1 0 1))
;Value: #*110101
```

Is converting it to a tail recursive function the solution here? If so, any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What Scheme are you using that has this restriction on recursion?

Comment: MIT-Scheme. It may also be related to my computer/system, which is relatively dated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A friend of mine solved it, pasted for any future queries:

```
(define (convert-integers-to-bits integer-representation-of-bits)
   (define (accum rest so-far)
     (if (null? rest)
       (bit-string-append so-far '#*)
       (accum   
         (cdr rest)      
         (bit-string-append     
           (unsigned-integer->bit-string 1 (car rest))
           so-far))))                               
    (accum integer-representation-of-bits '#*))
```

Comment: @dyoo good call :). I just tried but it says i have to wait 2 days. Also, thanks for answering questions, Im grateful that you're on Stackoverflow!

Comment: Note that this is exactly the kind of solution I'm suggesting.  `so-far` is the accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, converting it into tail recursion will fix the problem.  The best way to do this in this case is to use an *accumulator*.  This is a value that you pass along representing the computation you've already done, or what you have left to do.  For example, you could pass along the bit strings you've produced so far, and then do the `append` when you get to the end.

Comment: What would be the way to do this if you didn't want to use an accumulator?

Comment: You have to use an accumulator in some form -- even the stack as used in the regular recursive version is serving as the accumulator. Another place you could put the accumulator is in a variable that you mutate with `set!`.